# Store web related data when logged via facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to have login via facebook on my site, by even registration by email.
So i will have user table, where will be user id, email and other user related info.
But problem is i don't know how to store in my webapp data, that are related to user, which is logged via facebook. For instance if i need use foreign key to user table in another table, what key i should use for users, that are logged via facebook? Should i always check if user is logged first time and then create some additional record in user table?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing oauth login skeleton at this time. My approach is to have user table with primary key, name and email. There's another table oauthlogin that references user table and it has oauth provider type and identifier.